# Need a solution to design an automated system

Tags: java, python, automation, architecture, software-design

I have 5 exe files. each exe file takes an input and give back an output which will be the input to another exe file.and the user passing the values to the exe file manually now i want to automate this process by using one of the programming language. what should be my approach. how should i build an automation for the above scenario

for eg

```
input1 +input2 ->[ exe 1 ] ->output +input3 -> [ exe 2 ] -> output +input 4 ->
[ exe 3 ] -> output +input 5 -> [ exe 4 ] -> output -> [ exe 5 ] -> final output
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by output of the `.exe`s you're referring to console output, then I think the simplest way would be to use Python's `subprocess` module, giving your input as arguments and controlling the output of the executables.

```
import subprocess


def run_exe(exe_location, *args):
    arguments = " ".join(args)
    try:
        exe_output = subprocess.check_output(f"{exe_location} {arguments}")
        return exe_output
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
        print(f"There were issues encountered when running {exe_location}")
```

Therefore, you can orchestrate different possibilities of running different executables and capturing their output, to be used as input for other executables in the manner described in your example.

```
first_output = run_exe(first_exe_location, initial_input)

second_output = run_exe(second_exe_location, first_output, additional_input)
```

and the cycle can continue or be modified, based on the desired flow.